# Time Series Forecasting with GARCH

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to forecast a time series object in R with GARCH(1,1) model. My goal is to hav 24 instances ahead forecast with the GARCH model. Although I am using a time series object while forecasting,I get the following error:

**Error in is.constant(y) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**

Those are the commands that I am using:

```
library(forecast)
library(tseries)


trainer1 <- ts(trainer, frequency=24)
m1 <- garch(trainer1, order = c(1,1))
forecasts1 <- forecast(m1, h=24)
```

And the sample data that I am using is as follows:

```
124.30
98.99
64.00
64.00
123.99
123.99
34.97
123.99
139.91
140.00
164.30
178.99
140.00
169.95
161.18
139.94
161.31
124.00
115.01
124.00
```

Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `garch` is not a function of `forecast` package. So, you cannot apply `forecast` function on `m1` model. The `garch` function is available in `tseries` package. So, to use `garch` for prediction you have to use

```
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
trainer1 <- ts(df, frequency=24)
m1 <- garch(trainer1, order = c(1,1))
forecasts1 <- predict(m1, trainer1)
```

If you want to forecast you can use `fGarch` package like

```
library(fGarch)
fit <- garchFit(~ arma(0,1) + garch(1,1), data = trainer1, trace = FALSE)
predict(fit,n.ahead=24,plot=TRUE)
```

[image]

## Data

```
df = structure(list(trainer = c(124.3, 98.99, 64, 64, 123.99, 123.99, 
34.97, 123.99, 139.91, 140, 164.3, 178.99, 140, 169.95, 161.18, 
139.94, 161.31, 124, 115.01, 124)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```