# Error in is.constant(y) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a time series data set of the hidden unemployment rate. The data can be access via `gcmr` package. I tried to forecast `24` months but I cannot. Here is the code I used.

```
library(gcmr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
data("HUR", package = "gcmr")
plot(HUR, ylab = "rate", xlab = "time")
trend <- scale(time(HUR))
mod <- gcmr(HUR ~ trend | trend, marginal = beta.marg, cormat = arma.cormat(1, 3))
summary(mod)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(mod)
```

### The following returns the error.

```
forecasts1 <- predict(mod, HUR)
predict(mod,n.ahead=24,plot=TRUE)
```

**Please note that I have tried the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480098/time-series-forecasting-with-garch), but it did not solve my problem.**

Comment: Hi Maryam. `predict` is a generic function. That means it will dispatch according to the class of the object you pass it. For example, if you use `glm` to create a model and call `predict` on that model, then it will see that the class of the model is `glm` and call `predict.glm`. There has to be a `predict` method available for the class, otherwise `predict` won't know what to do with it. It's a bit like trying `mean(c("a", "b", "c"))` - the `mean` function just doesn't know what to do with a character vector. In your case the model is class `gcmr`, and there is no `predict.gcmr`

Comment: @Allan Amazing help. Thanks a lot.